# OpenNMS: Can I do Industrial IOT and LTE Mobility

Tags: iot, lte, opennms

Hi everyone I am new to OpenNMS and for now I am in learning phase. I have request from one of my client to done some research on the following two thing.

1- Can we do Industrial IOT with OpenNMS

2- Private LTE mobility and Monitoring of devices

I have very short time to conclude the result and give it back to the client. Although I searched myself for these points but I cannot conclude because I have not in depth understanding for OpenNMS for now. So my questions is can we do these features in OpenNMS. Its really helpful If someone with more experience in OpenNMS share his thoughts. **Please don't consider the details about devices and their protocol I just want to know if OpenNMS is capable for doing industrial IOT for oil, gas and mining sectors.**

Note: My client already have NMS build in OpenNMS that is why he is interested in OpenNMS for these features.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [MQTT Plugin](https://github.com/opennms-forge/opennms-mqtt-plugin) developed which allows to consume event data and performance data over MQTT. Craig Gallen is the main author and gave a [talk about OpenNMS and IoT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r8GXg_DSUM4) capabilities at our conference. I personally gave it a try and got it work with Mosquitto MQTT broker and some sensor using Home Assistent. I've documented my findings here: https://pad.no42.org/uHN8csNkQB23rJsgt62SlQ.

The plugin is in early stage and need probably some more iterations. I hope the information help you to get more ideas where OpenNMS is heading. Feel free for more questions in our [chat in channel opennms-discussion](https://chat.opennms.com).

Answer (score 0):

I've been involved with using OpenNMS for IoT data collection for years. Also a professional geologist having worked in O&G and mining. Short answer is yes.

Comment: can you contextualize more your answer? Show examples etc.

Comment: OpenNMS has tools to collect time series data via collectd, snmp polling, clients ("minions") placed at the edge, and now mqtt messages. It has nearly all the tools needed to collect the time series and event information from IoT sensors.